# Why I'm getting a POST http://localhost:3000/upload 404 (Not Found)?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, axios

I am making a project that has a React frontend and a Django backend. I was working with the Upload functionality for this project. Users can upload files from the React frontend which will then be uploaded to the media folder in the Django backend. Files are then processed in the Django backend and response data is send to the React frontend.

So this is the code for my upload component for the frontend.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './Upload.css'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Upload() {

    const [selected,setSelected] = useState(null)
    const config = {headers:{"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}}



    const onChangeHandler=event=>{
        setSelected(event.target.files)
    }

    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/';

    const onClickHandler = async () => {
        const data = new FormData()
        for(var x = 0; x<selected.length; x++) {
            data.append('file', selected[x])
        }

     try{
       const resp = await axios.post(url, data,config)
       console.log(resp.data)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err.response)
    }
}
    

    return (
        <div className="upload-container">

            <form method="post" 
            encType="multipart/form-data"
            onSubmit={onClickHandler}
            >
    
            <input type="file" name="myfile" multiple onChange={onChangeHandler} />
            <input type="submit"  />
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the core urls.py file at the Django backend. The upload component of react has a route of '/upload'. So, I have created an upload path in the URLs which in turn is linked to Scanner.urls. Scanner is an app I've created in Django where the uploaded files will be posted and processed.

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('upload/',include('Scanner.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

This is the urls.py file in Scanner app.

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.upload)
]
```

And this is the upload function in views.py file of Scanner app. Besides the upload function, there are other helper functions inside the views.py file that are used in the upload method to process the files.

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.name):
                filename= file.name
                fs.save(file.name, file)
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'media/')
            

        data = ScanFiles(target)
        ext = data[1]
        mylist = data[0][0]

        for l in mylist:
            if l[1] != []:
                tup = VariablesData(l[1],ext)
                l[1] = []
                l[1].append(tup[0])
                l[1].append(tup[1])
                l[1].append(tup[2])

        for l in mylist:
            if l[2] != []:
                tup2 = MethodsData(l[2],ext)
                l[2] = []
                l[2].append(tup2[0])
                l[2].append(tup2[1])
                l[2].append(tup2[2])
                l[2].append(tup2[3])


        print(mylist)
        return Response(mylist,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

[So, when I post the files from the React frontend, I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfJfM.jpg)

[While this is the error on the Django server. The gibberish above the error is just some data I've printed from files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBvMM.jpg)

Why I'm getting these errors? Files are uploaded to the django server and processed, as shown by the print statement output in the Django backend. But, why I get this error and why I'm able to send response data to the React frontend. Please guide.

Comment: can you please check your server port ?! 
in second image the port 60760, and you use 8000 in your code and the error with port 3000 ?!  i think it's related.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou I believe port 60760 is from the browser, port 8000 is Django server and port 3000 is React. The error is likely as I describe below because the form submission is not prevented.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou well I checked this. The server when starts, it runs on port 8000. But, every time, that error as shown in the image comes, I get a different port every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't prevented the submission of the form so when you submit the form, first your code makes a request to the Django server, and then continues to make a request to the React frontend which does not allow a POST request to the url. Hence you receive an error.

How to solve this? Just prevent the form submission in your `onSubmit` handler:

```
const onClickHandler = async (e) => { // take the event as a parameter here
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    const data = new FormData()
    for(var x = 0; x<selected.length; x++) {
        data.append('file', selected[x])
    }
    try{
        const resp = await axios.post(url, data,config)
        console.log(resp.data)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err.response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I restarted the app. It worked. You're a lifesaver.